# How to create a seperate directory for admin controller in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I am new to cakephp development. I have create user controller to register, login & update own profile in the user table. I can access the user controller with `http://local-host/my_project/user/login`.

I have also a admin table in database so that admin can login and manage user in my project. I want to create a folder separate folder (ex: admin) in the controller directory so that i can access the controller files using `http://local-host/my_project/admin/controller/login` & `http://local-host/my_project/admin/controller/manage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at 'prefix routing' in the manual, it seems that this is what you're looking for:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

With prefix routing, you'll be able to add, for example, an action admin_overview() to your User controller which is then accessible via the URL /admin/users/overview. The 'admin' prefixed action will *not* overlap with non-admin actions (e.g. 'overview()'), which will be accessible via the 'regular' URL; /users/overview/

Of course, you can create separate admin controller(s) for this purpose, but you may need to create custom routes. For more advanced options regarding routing, it's worth your time to read the whole chapter (or, even better) read the whole cake cookbook, it's also available as eBook for offline reading;
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html

Another solution is to develop the 'admin' part of your application as a plugin. This will keep your frontend and backend controllers/models/views separated. As a bonus, the backend may can be re-used for other projects as well (depending on its design of course)

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#creating-your-own-plugins

Comment: thank your for your reply. But i would like to add a folder to the app/controller directory so that i can store backend (admin related) controller to that. Can u please tell me the core concept to do that....

Comment: @ShahAlom Why would you want to do so? The location of a controller does *not* make a difference for the URL because that is determined by the 'routes'. Using routes, you are free to define *any* url for an action. If you want to 'physically' separate your 'Admin' controllers/views/models from the rest of your application, you might consider developing them as a plugin.

Comment: Thank you @thaJeztah,  I am doing a big project with may 50 controller and a lot action for frontend. If i use any controller for frontend & backend, the main problem will If i use any action for frontend, i can't use that for backend. same way if i use any action for backend, i can't use that for frontend.

Comment: All solutions will allow you to do so; prefix-routing (admin_edit() and edit() won't overlap), however, developing the backend as a plugin is what we normally do. This keeps a clear separation between frontend/public and backend/admin controllers/views/models. (You can 'share' the models if you desire to do so). As an extra bonus, the admin-plugin may be reusable for multiple projects

Comment: How do you share the models @thaJeztah?

Comment: @bigmike7801 We have separate 'app' and 'admin' models for the same tables (the admin models are inside the plugin);
this allows the 'app' models to have methods tailored at the 'app', but aren't useful in the admin plugin, and vice-versa. 

Most admin models can be quite basic and reusable parts of the models are implemented as behaviors. Also, our 'app' models generally 
use a non-priviledged database-connection (only write access where nescessary)

Comment: @thaJeztah, would you mind looking at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725234/how-to-structure-my-cakephp-admin-plugin

Comment: Plugin would be a better idea.