# How to structure my CakePHP admin plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins

I'm considering creating a plugin for the admin portion of my application and am seeking some guidance on how it should be structured. I will be using `CakePHP 2.5.x`.

**Part 1:**

I will be Auth as well as Acl. Should I be configuring this within `/app/Controller/AppController.php` or `/app/Plugin/MyPlugin/Controller/MyPluginAppController.php`?

**Part 2:**

Let's say I want to access the Post Model: `/app/Model/AppController.php` from within my plugin. What's the best way to do this within my plugin?

Which one of these files should I create to handle this? Do I even need to create a model within my plugin if I'm just extending the model from the main app?:

```
//Model
/app/Plugin/MyPlugin/Model/Post.php //Will this conflict with /app/Controller/PostsController.php?
/app/Plugin/MyPlugin/Model/MyPluginPost.php 

//Controller
/app/Plugin/MyPlugin/Controller/PostsController.php //Will this conflict with /app/Controller/PostsController.php?
/app/Plugin/MyPlugin/Controller/MyPluginPostsController.php
```

How should I handle the data within the plugin's Post Controller? Am I on the right track with this?

```
<?php
// app/Plugin/MyPlugin/Controller/MyPluginAppController.php
App::uses('Posts.Post', 'Controller');
class MyPluginPostsController extends MyPluginAppController {

        public function index() {
            $this->Post->recursive = 0;
            $this->set('posts', $this->Paginator->paginate());
            return $this->Crud->execute();
        }
}
```

I realize I've asked a lot of questions, I just want to make sure what I'm doing is feasible/logical.

Comment: Using a plugin doesn't make much sense IMHO, use prefix routing instead.

Comment: I have seen others say that building an admin plugin "keeps a clear separation between frontend/public and backend/admin controllers/views/models. (You can 'share' the models if you desire to do so). As an extra bonus, the admin-plugin may be reusable for multiple projects".

Comment: *Who* says so? I disagree because it is in fact **not** separated because none of both will work without each other because you'll have to share the models and if done properly (fat models) the models *will* contain admin related code as well. You'll have two pieces with tight coupling - no separation. Nor will the plugin be usable in any other projects except it is a *very* generic and rudimentary plugin and in this case you can use the CRUD plugin from the "Friends of Cake" repo on Github as well which is at least customizable through events.

Comment: I saw it on this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909579/how-to-create-a-seperate-directory-for-admin-controller-in-cakephp/14909642#comment20932919_14909642 as well as some other forums.

Comment: Well, I still disagree and named my reasons. ;) Except you really get it done totally separated but in this case you can directly use the CRUD plugin. In reality every app has it's own special cases that are specific to the app. Creating a base plugin and extending it in another plugin would be another option and a clean solution.